# callbacks calling continuously angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, calendar, primeng

Hi there I have this piece of code:

```
*p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startDate" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24" showIcon="true" [minDate]="minDate" [Focus]="test()"*
```

This is Calendar from Primeng I'm using this Callback 'Focus' and it is calling itself continuously even if the element is not in focus. 
This is happening with all the other callbacks in other modules too. Is this is a known behavior or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch focus event you need to use `[onFocus]` and NOT `[Focus]`.
     More info : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

As @Manos Kaparos wrote you should use "onFocus" to catch the event using () instead of []:

```
p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startDate" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24" 
showIcon="true" [minDate]="minDate" (onFocus)="test()"
```

hope it hepls!

Comment: ok as I was using [onFocus] it was giving error because of security reasons I should use 'Focus' instead of onFocus, but I was using it the wrong way altogether. thanks I will give it a try then!